# Can I get the method that was first called in an error routine?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am trying to get the method that called a method in an assembly that caused an error.

I have an error routine that logs errors.  I would like to get the calling assembly and method along with the assembly and method where the error occurred.  I got 3 out of 4, I just cant figure out how to get the calling method.

Say I have a form and a button is clicked that calls a method in another asssembly that errors.  I want the assembly and method where the error occurs along with the form and click event.  The click event is what I can't find.

VB

```
Dim Trace As System.Diagnostics.StackTrace
Trace = New System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(ex, True)

'Returns the assembly where the error occurred
Trace.GetFrame(Trace.FrameCount - 1).GetMethod.ReflectedType.FullName

'Returns the calling assembly
Assembly.GetCallingAssembly.FullName.Split(","c)(0)'Would be nice to get the class too but I can live without it.

'Method where the error occurs
ex.TargetSite.Name

'Initial calling method
???
```

C#

```
System.Diagnostics.StackTrace Trace;
Trace = New System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(ex, True);

//Returns the assembly where the error occurred
Trace.GetFrame(Trace.FrameCount - 1).GetMethod().ReflectedType.FullName;

//Returns the calling assembly
Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().FullName.Split(',')[0];//Would be nice to get the class too but I can live without it.

//Method where the error occurs
ex.TargetSite.Name;

//Initial calling method
???
```

[image]

I can see the source in the stack trace (Main.btnCancel_CLick but can not get it.  My stacktrace frame count is 1 and I have one method in there, the one with the try catch block.  Unless there's some other way to get to it that I can't figure out.  Anyone know?